# What is the valid string representation of tstzrange[]?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to find string representation of `tstzrange[]` type (array of timestamp ranges):

```
select '{[2014-01-01,2015-01-01]}'::tstzrange[];
select '{''[2014-01-01,2015-01-01]''}'::tstzrange[];
select '{[''2014-01-01'',''2015-01-01'']}'::tstzrange[];
```

But each of queries above throws `malformed range literal` error.

I know that I can use `array[tstzrange('2014-01-01','2015-01-01','[]')]` but what I need is a string representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that here you have to combine two literals: `'{}'` for the array and `'[...,...]'` for the range type.

In all these cases, the easiest is just getting back the output from the system itself:

```
SELECT array[tstzrange('2014-01-01','2015-01-01','[]')];
                            array                            
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 {"[\"2014-01-01 00:00:00+01\",\"2015-01-01 00:00:00+01\"]"}
```

Now you simply wrap this into quotes, and there you are.

There is, however, a simpler way, which *usually* works: just double-quote the inner literal.  See:

```
select '{"[2014-01-01,2015-01-01]"}'::tstzrange[];
                          tstzrange                          
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 {"[\"2014-01-01 00:00:00+01\",\"2015-01-01 00:00:00+01\"]"}
```

Note that the output is the same as above.